# Why does ((self=[super init]]) work, but (!(self=[super init])) doesn't?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

For aesthetic reasons, I decided to change this:

```
if ((self = [super init])) {
    // init self
}
return self;
```

Into this:

```
if (!(self = [super init])) return nil;
// init self
return self;
```

In theory, they do the same thing. The first one is the classic way, simply works.  Debugging the second one, I found that it almost worked. The "if" does it right, the init code also, but, after returning "self", the debugger get back to the "if" and returns nil!

All classes I made with the second one I'm reverting to use the "correct" way because they where initing with nil, but I really want to know why does it behaves like that! I'm afraid that this may be the result of something else wrong!

Comment: If this happens in Xcode 4, then the reason is that the debugger just sucks and jumps wildly around in ObjC methods.

Comment: That's not a debugger-only behavior. It really returns "nil" to the caller. Oh, and the init code is called (including some "NSLog"s I put there.

Comment: @Eduardo Costa: Alright, then never mind my comment.

Comment: It's rather straightforward: if condition is true, then [super init] returns nil. Check the superclass init (make sure it is not nil).

Comment: As I said, it works only by switching from the second one to the first one. This means [super init] IS NOT returning nil. BTW, the class's super is NSObject.

Comment: How could your method return both self and nil?

Comment: IMHO: Assignments within the predicate part of an if statement are code smells.

Comment: Please provide a minimal test case that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Nick: This kind of assignment is boilerplate -- convention -- it's just the way this is done in Cocoa. Doing it differently only hampers readability.

Comment: @Josh Caswell nothing is wrong with moving the `self = [super init]` one line above  and test against `if (self) {` And no one can tell me that this worsens readability.

Comment: @Nick / @Josh: In fact, moving the assignment out of the if() seems to be the the preferred way at Apple now.

Comment: Are you sure you only use one "=" in your reworked code?

Comment: @All I've just had a look at several Books: The Objective-C Programming Language by Apple, Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X by A.Hillegass or Cocoa Design Patterns by Buck & Yacktman, no one does the assignment in the predicate area of the if statement.

Comment: @Bavarious I'm trying to create a small test case, but without success. As I said in Nick's answer, I believe some sort of buffer overflow happened, but it does not explain why my init code run and then return nil. I had the hope that answer could be "!nil == FALSE" or something - like in SQL: "NULL = anything" is false and "NULL <> anything" is also false!

Comment: @Nick: You are quite correct, that's another way it's done, but it's possible to come up with examples of the one-line style (see the OmniFrameworks -- don't tell me _their_ code smells! -- or ZSync). I'll revise my statement to be weaker:  I'm just not sure it's worth being upset about this style, since any Cocoa developer reading it doesn't have to think about it any more than the two-line way. _Generally_, yes, assignments in if predicates are suspicious, but there are idiomatic usages, like this one. @Eiko

Comment: @Josh not being upset, all good, just saying what I think about this particular case.

Comment: @Nick: "Upset" may have been too strong a word again, sorry. :) I meant it very loosely. I certainly respect your thoughts, and discussions about technical tidbits like this can be enjoyable.

Comment: I would recommend style `self = [super init]; if (!self) {return nil}; //init code return self;` Your programming style should be easy to read, don't mix two actions into one line. And @Josh, @Nick, Apple's programming style sucks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's absolutely no difference between your two versions other than aesthetic preference, so something else must be going wrong. Perhaps you should post your whole `init` method?

Comment: This class is a tree node with lots of interdependences. I will need to post my whole project to make it useful. But I believe some kind of buffer overflow happened, since I cannot reproduce it in simple tests. BTW, it does not explain why an external error makes my init code run and then return nil!

Comment: @Eduardo If you don’t provide further information, it’s unlikely someone will be able to guess what’s wrong with your code.

Comment: @Bavarious Yes, I know. As I said, I guess some buffer overflow happened - does not explains the "nil return", but I made new classes with this technique and it is working as desired. I'm marking this answer as "correct", because I'll assume "something else must be going wrong".

Answer (score 1):

I created a test class for this, with the following init method:

```
- (id)init
{
    if (!(self = [super init])) return nil;
    [self setText:@"foo"];
    return self;
}
```

It initializes as expected, and I can access the text property. So as Nick pointed out, something else must be malfunctioning.